# Group $(R,*)$, where $a*b=|a|b$

Tags: group-theory

Let $R$ be the group of the nonzero real numbers under multiplication, and define $a*b=|a|b$. I want to know which of the following are true

I. $(R, *)$ has a left identity.

II. $(R,*)$ is left cancellative, i.e. $a*b=a*c$ implies $b=c$.

III. $(R,*)$ is a group.

By definition, I can get two left identities $-1$ and $1$. Can I just say it's not a group since the left identity is not unique? What is the right identity if it exists? I can get $a*e=|a|e=|a|=a$ but it seems like it depends on $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$ is a right identity, then you don't know that $|a|e=|a|$. So you have to go straight for $|a|e=a$. Then note that, say, $a=3$ and $a=-3$ require different right identities. So there is no right identity. (It's not enough to say that it *seems* to depend on $a$. You have to pick two different $a$, or something like that, and *show* that it depends on $a$.)

As for left cancellation, if $|a|b=|a|c$, then $b=c$. So that's something we have in this semigroup.

Comment: Hello, sir. If the right identity does not exist because it's not unique, then why the left identity exists?

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 He's saying a right identity doesn't exist; that's different to saying it's not unique.

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 As left identity, both $1$ and $-1$ work all the time. On the other hand, as a right identity, $1$ works sometimes and $-1$ works sometimes.

Comment: @Arthur I see. Thank you sir.